# How to retrieve the content of <script src="myscript.ms"></script>

Tags: html, dom, browser

if it was inline instead of src it would be easy to use innerHTML however it returns blank...so i assume the src attribute makes the content of myscript.ms not go into the dom as it normally does for inline script.

How can I access the data in myscript.ms file short of using some internal browser extension method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_xmlhttprequest

didnt know XHR could be used for non http requests.